# fwrite em determinada linha PHP

Tags: php

Desejo escrever um determinado codigo em uma determinada linha de um arquivo com PHP.

```
<?php
$arquivo_origem = "client.php";
$arquivo_destino = "copiado.php";

if (copy($arquivo_origem, $arquivo_destino)){
    echo "Sucesso!";

}


$teste = "Eu sei";

$handle = fopen( $arquivo_destino, 'a+' );

$ler = fwrite( $handle, $teste );

// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($handle);


?>
```

Desejava escrever a minha variavel $teste na linha 17 do meu $arquivo_destino.

No caso como faço?

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer algo assim:

```
<?php

$file = $arquivo_destino;
$line_looking = 16; //lembre que a contagem começa em 0

$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$lines[$line_looking] = 'Linha substituida';
file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $lines));
```

---

Um exemplo -> http://ideone.com/9XtaS5

Comment: Bom Dia, no meu caso eu queria substituir a linha, porem o meu codigo completo está assim: http://pastebin.com/Za4q4Sxq Porém ele cria o arquivo cola o codigo mas não substitui a linha, pode me indicar o erro?

Comment: possivelmente porque você ta abrindo o arquivo duas vezes, a primeira em modo de append na linha 14 e depois na linha 21, remova a linha 14 ($handle = fopen( $arquivo_destino, 'a+' );) e a linha 26 ($handle = fopen( $arquivo_destino, 'a+' );)

Comment: Bom Dia, Continua o mesmo imprime o arquivo mas não substitui a linha.

Comment: aqui funciona de boa

Comment: pode ver um exemplo aqui http://ideone.com/9XtaS5

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @Adir Kuhn, caso você precise inserir no meio e não substituir, pode fazer assim:

```
$arquivo = '/dir/ate/arquivo.ext';
$numero_linha = 17;
$conteudo_linha = 'teste';

$linhas = file($arquivo); // lê o arquivo na forma de array (cada linha é um elemento)
$final_array = array_splice($linhas, $numero_linha-1); // corta array ($linhas fica com a primeira parte; array_splice retorna a parte cortada)
$linhas[] = $conteudo_linha . "\n"; // adiciona após a posição cortada
$linhas = array_merge($linhas, $final_array); // junta novamente
file_put_contents($arquivo, $linhas);
```

Comment: No caso desejo substituir, veja o meu comentario abaixo por favor.